# Is it possible to use and update the same state by many mapWithState functions in a single batch in Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in Spark Streaming framework which is relatively similar to PageRank.

Unfortunately I found that when I wrote mapWithState multiple times:

```
val mappedWithState = wordCounts
.mapWithState[Long, (String, Long)](spec)
.mapWithState[Long, (String, Long)](spec)
.mapWithState[Long, (String, Long)](spec)
```

every mapWithState create and use its own state.

Is it possible to use and update this same state many times in single batch? I know that exist StreamContext.remember(someDuration) method, but it looks very expensive.